# Spring MVC @Scope proxy bean & Jackson 2

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I'm trying to develop a small Spring MVC application, where i'd like User object to initialize from the beginning of each session.

I have the User class

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class MyUser implements User {

    // private fields
    // getters and setters


    public void fillByName(String username) {
        userDao.select(username);
    }

}
```

And i want to initialize MyUser object once Spring Security recognize the user, in Interceptor Class *(Btw, is it a good practice?)*

```
public class AppInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Autowired
    MyUser user;

    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        if (!(auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) {
            user.fillByName(auth.getName());
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

So, when Controller handles the request, there is already initialized session scoped User class. But when i try to serialize MyUser object with Jackson, it just doesnt't work:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
    public String launchApp(ModelMap model) {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        try {
            System.out.println(user.getUsername()); // Works good!
            model.addAttribute("user", mapper.writeValueAsString(user)); // Doesn't work
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            // @todo log an error
        }

        return "app/base";
    }
```

As you can see, MyUser object getters work good from the Controller class, but Jackson - doesn't.

When i remove @Scope annotation from User object, Jackson serialization start working.

Obviously, scoped proxy bean and singleton Controller class are the problem

But how i can fix it?

--

UPDATE

Looks like i'm first who came across this :)
Maybe it is bad architecture? Should i create a new instance of MyUser class in the Controller? What is the common practice?

Answer (score 5):

The reason for this is that your `proxyMode` is set to `TARGET_CLASS`, which instructs Spring to create a class-based proxy for your class (essentially a new class that implements the interface of the original class, but might not be compatible with the way `ObjectMapper` converts objects into string).

You can solve this by telling `ObjectMapper` which class signatures to use when writing the object by using `writerFor` as such:

```
mapper.writerFor(User.class).writeValueAsString(user)
```

Or if you already have a custom writer, use `forClass`, like this:

```
writer.forClass(User.class).writeValueAsString(user)
```

Answer (score 4):

One way that I can think of is to add yet another wrapper:

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class MyScopedUser implements User {

    private MyUser myUser;
    // private fields
    // getters and setters


    public void fillByName(String username) {
        userDao.select(username);
    }

    public MyUser getMyUser() {
        return this.myUser;
    }
}
```

So now your `MyScopedUser` is a scoped proxy, but the core user is a normal class. You can get the user out and marshal later on:

```
mapper.writeValueAsString(scopeUser.getMyUser())
```